# Netlogo: how to assign list values to patches attributes

Tags: list, attributes, netlogo, patch

i am new to Netlogo, so i apologize if this is a trivial question. I would like to assign/copy the values of a list into patches attribute, making sure that the order of the values is respected. The following code does the opposite, that is, it copies the values of a patches attribute (attr1) into list1

```
patches-own [ attr1 attr2]
to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [set attr1 random 10]  
  let patch-list sort patches
  let list1 map [ p -> [attr1] of p ] patch-list
end
```

now, say that I would like to assign/copy the values of varX into patches attribute attr2, making sure that the order of the values is respected.

```
  let nPix world-width * world-height 
  let varX (range nPix)
  
  ????
```

any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let Netlogo iterate through two lists simultanously by feeding the anonymous procedure two inputs. To do that, you need to put brackets around the  entire procedure.

```
patches-own [attr2]

to setup
  
  ca
  resize-world 0 4 0 4
  
end

to go
  
  let nPix world-width * world-height 
  let varX n-values nPix [random 140]

  (foreach sort patches varX [ [the-patch the-var] ->
    ask the-patch [set attr2 the-var]
    ]
  )

  show varX
  ask patches [set pcolor attr2]
  
end
```

You can also always opt for a good old while loop where you increment an index (i) within the loop and use that index to couple the corresponding items from both lists.

```
to go-3
  
  let nPix world-width * world-height 
  let varX n-values nPix [random 140]
  
  let patch-list sort patches
  
  let i 0
  while [i < nPix] [
    ask item i patch-list [set attr2 item i varX]
    set i i + 1
  ]
  
  show varX
  ask patches [set pcolor attr2]
  
end
```